# xpath for a google search url issue no content

Tags: xpath

http://www.google.com/search?q=youtube

Trying to get the url part www.youtube.com/ of the search

using this xpath but there is no output from it.

```
.//*[@id='rso']/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/cite
```

i've also tried using the css path same issue

Comment: Works OK. What tool are you using to select the URL and how? Show us the code, we love code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS: `div[aria-label='Result details']+div>div cite`.
Btw, your xpath works fine for me. If you use selenium to retrieve your text for example, you should write `xpath=.//` in this case, because it recognize selector as xpath by preceding `//` symbols. Also `//*[@id='rso']/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/cite//text()` will return three textNodes `www.`, `youtube` and `.com/`